# объединить массивы php на подобии array_combine, но не склеить, а получить вложенный массив?

Tags: php, массивы

объединить массивы php на подобии array_combine, но не склеить, а получить вложенный массив?

массив 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => xxx1
    [1] => xxx2
    [2] => xxx3
    [3] => xxx4
    [4] => xxx5
    [5] => xxx6
)
```

массив 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => yyy1
    [1] => yyy2
    [2] => yyy3
    [3] => yyy4
    [4] => yyy4
    [5] => yyy4
)
```

получить на выходе

```
Array
(
    [yyy1] => xxx1
    [yyy2] => xxx2
    [yyy3] => xxx3
    [yyy4] => Array (xxx4, xxx5, xxx6)
)
```

**UPDATE**
вообщем задача такова:
2 массива, оба равны по количеству пар ключ=>значение (это условие постоянно)

далее: в массиве 1 есть некое значение которое мы ловим скажем оно "X", оно повторяться может n-раз.

нужно получить ключи "X" и по этим ключам создать массив из значений моссива2

массив1

```
(
    [0] => tresh1
    [1] => tresh2
    [2] => X
    [3] => X
    [4] => tresh3
)
```

массив2

```
(
    [0] => tresh11
    [1] => tresh22
    [2] => need1
    [3] => need2
    [4] => tresh33
)
```

на выходе

```
(
    [X] => Array(need1, need2)
)
```

Comment: На чем основана логика такая? Мне вот лично не ясно... что вы пробовали? Что не получилось?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, пробовал array_combine получаю:
(
    [yyy1] => xxx1
    [yyy2] => xxx2
    [yyy3] => xxx3
    [yyy4] => xxx6
)
в "yyy4" только последнее значение,
а мне нужны все значения.

Comment: логика то все равно не ясна.. что будет если в массиве, выступающим в роли ключей будет `yyy1/yyy2/yyy3/yyy5/yyy6/yyy4` или в массиве со значениями `xxx1/xxx1/xxx2/xxx3/xxx4/xxx4`..... и т.д.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил UPDATE с более "ясным" описанием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$first = [
    'yyy1',
    'yyy2',
    'yyy3',
    'yyy4',
    'yyy4',
    'yyy4'
];

$second = [
    'xxx1',
    'xxx2',
    'xxx3',
    'xxx4',
    'xxx5',
    'xxx6'
];

$countKeys = count($first);
$new = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $countKeys; $i++) {
    if(array_key_exists($first[$i], $new)){
        if(is_array($new[$first[$i]])){
            $new[$first[$i]][]=$second[$i];
        }else{
            $new[$first[$i]] = [$new[$first[$i]], $second[$i]];
        }
    }else{
        $new[$first[$i]] = $second[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо огромное!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$keys = array(
    'yyy1',
    'yyy2',
    'yyy3',
    'yyy4',
    'yyy4',
    'yyy4',
);

$values = array(
    'xxx1',
    'xxx2',
    'xxx3',
    'xxx4',
    'xxx5',
    'xxx6',
);

$countElements = count($keys);
$output = array();
for ($index = 0; $index < $countElements; $index++) {
    $key = $keys[$index];
    $value = $values[$index];
    $keyExists = array_key_exists($key, $output);
    if (!$keyExists) {
        $output[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $output[$key] = array_merge((array) $output[$key], array($value));
    }
}
```

извиняюсь писал на телефоне поправил ошибки.

результат:

```
Array
(
    [yyy1] => xxx1
    [yyy2] => xxx2
    [yyy3] => xxx3
    [yyy4] => Array
        (
            [0] => xxx4
            [1] => xxx5
            [2] => xxx6
        )

)
```

Comment: у вашей функции результат такой же как у array_combine, мне не подходит, он записывает ключ с последним значением...
Array
(
    [yyy1] => xxx1
    [yyy2] => xxx2
    [yyy3] => xxx3
    [yyy4] => xxx6
)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y3', 'y4', 'y4', 'y4'];
$b = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7'];
```

---

```
// 1
$result = [];
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    $result = array_merge_recursive($result, [$val => $b[$key]]);
}
```

---

```
// 2
$result = array_reduce(array_keys($a), function (&$carry, $key) use ($a, $b) {
    return $carry = array_merge_recursive($carry, [$a[$key] => $b[$key]]);
}, []);
```

---

```
// 3
$result = [];
array_walk($a, function ($val, $key, $b) use (&$result) {
    $result = array_merge_recursive($result, [$val => $b[$key]]);
}, $b);
```

---

```
// 4
$result = [];
array_map(function ($aVal, $bVal) use (&$result) {
    $result = array_merge_recursive($result, [$aVal => $bVal]);
}, $a, $b);
```

---

```
// 5
$result = [];
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    $result[$val] = array_key_exists($val, $result)
        ? array_merge((array) $result[$val], (array) $b[$key])
        : $b[$key];
};
```